# Include a link from the meta profile to the main profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, meta, per-site-meta

As I'm sure everyone knows, the user account on meta sites of new SE beta sites are tied to the user accounts of the main site and the profile pages on the meta sites are slightly cut down (there is no related accounts tab).

Should the users meta profile page include a link to the main sites user profile page, or perhaps the related accounts tab should be reinstated in some limited form.

Edit: As Grace Note says, a two way link would be even better.

Comment: I think it would be great to have a two-way link, myself.

Comment: @Grace: Good point, I've edited to include your suggestion.

Comment: The one-way version from the Meta to the parent is now implemented in the form of a "parent user" link beneath the user's Gravatar.

Answer (score 1):

We'll definitely need the related accounts tab in the future when they link to similar sites.