# Meta/Parent link should take users to mirror page

Tags: feature-request, meta, navigation

The link to parent/meta should take you to the same or 'mirror' page on the other site.

For example, if I am looking at someone's meta profile, and I click parent, I'd like to go to their parent profile.

Or, if I am looking at a list of newest questions on meta, it should take me to that same list on parent.

I understand that this would be impossible for tag or question pages.

Comment: -1 because I think menu links are more usable when they are static.

Comment: @Jon, I guess I see it like Zelda, a Link to The past.  Where Parent is the light world, and meta is the dark world.  And, the links at the top are a portal between worlds.

Comment: @jinguy - you have out nerded me.

Comment: +1. And +30 for still remembering SNES games

Answer (score 2):

Well, for user pages specifically, we do have a [one way portal to the Parent Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57770/help-i-dont-have-the-moon-pearl-and-im-stuck-on-meta).

I don't see much really necessary use on any other pages, and I ponder that implementing it on the question sorts would actually be confusing. In the current system, the site will remember which sort order you last visited as opposed to which one you last assigned (which is conducive to keeping you on Newest, anyway). Were this implemented, I would have to juggle my sort filter constantly to keep Stack Overflow on Newest while keeping Meta Stack Overflow on Active. Either that, or always have to navigate to the homepage before navigating to the Meta site.

You close on impossible points, which also brings up consistency - the lack of any useful method to implement this for specific posts and tags means that we would need some default to fall back on. Since posts and tags represent a fairly large portion of the site that someone might be on when deciding to transition, they might get accustomed to always ending up on the default page. Yet suddenly, on a specific selection of pages, that same link will not lead to the default page. It's easier going from the transition-allowed pages to running into a default, but the other way is going to trip up a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Once again the "Questions that may already have your answer" worked and I found this question before asking it again.)</sub>

It's been two years, and we now have more user pages: I'd like this feature even if it only worked for our own user pages.

In other words, this OP's suggestion of all pages where possible link to corresponding pages in the other site would be great, but even if it is just that, when you're displaying any of your own user pages, the meta/main link actually just goes to your corresponding page on the other site, it would be good.

Even if it just went to your user summary it would save one click. I understand and agree a small a change as that would be bad for UI simplicity and understanding, but I'd prefer it...

Of course, I'd prefer more, though, as I said above, it doesn't *have* to be the whole site like the OP suggests.