# From meta user to main site user

Tags: feature-request, meta, user-accounts

When you see user on meta, you sometimes wonder what the corresponding SO account is.  Sometimes you can guess and search on the [user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users), but this is tedious and doesn't always work (or might even show the wrong user.)

[This similiar feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57770/137265) is marked as "completed".  It suggests that a link is implemented "below the gravatar".  I can't seem to find the link there.

Would it be useful to have a link from meta to main user?

Comment: Like in the "Accounts" section of the profile?

Comment: Per site Meta profiles have a handy "main user" link. Check, for example, my [Meta ProgSE profile](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/users/25936/yannis-rizos) (the link is at the top right, under "ask question"). MSO profiles, however, can't have that link because MSO doubles as the network Meta, lots of people here don't even have a SO account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible. Click on their user profile link, and scroll down to accounts. Click on "Stack Overflow".

Comment: +1 Thanks!  This post was the first that I understood.  Don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @Andomar; Neither do I, but this is Meta!. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 15):

### Right here.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Nice use of pictures. Could you add some red freehand circles?

Comment: @AndrewC Done :)

Comment: Superb! That's the ticket.

Comment: Nice answer. And congrats on 1000 (which you just got)!

Comment: @Linuxios If only it was so easy to gain rep on main SO...

Comment: @Undo: People are much more liberal with upvotes here.

Answer (score 4):

First, click on their name to go to their profile:

> [image]

Then go to the "Accounts" section and click on their Stack Overflow profile:

> [image]

Comment: +10 for freehand circle. -9 because I don't want to lose my diamond to vote fraud.

Comment: @AndrewBarber come now, nobody's gonna notice a few tiny votes missing? It's not like we care about them around here or anything...